# iOS- Provisioning profile issues.

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, xcode5, provisioning-profile

OK, so I have tried everything possible but still having issues.

I am testing on two devices. An iPhone and an iPad. When I connect the iPhone to Xcode and hit run it builds on the iPhone without any problems but when I connect the iPad to Xcode and hit run it fails and gives me this

> This product type must be built using a provisioning profile, however
>   no provisioning profile matching both the identity

I used to be able to test very easily before I upgraded to Xcode5.

Now it works on one device but not the other. Can anyone please tell me how I can fix this?

All my devices are upgraded to iOS 7.1 as well.

Comment: Have you added your iPad device in your provisioning profile?

Comment: Yes. I used to be able to test on it before I upgraded it to 7.1 and on Xcode 4.5 it used to work perfectly but doesn't work anymore after I did the upgrades.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to fix this problem, please follow these steps:

I. Go to Xcode Settings (Xcode -> Preferences), and select "Accounts." Make sure you are signed in to your developer account.

[image]

II. Click on the first tab under the run button, and then click on the name of the project (circled in red)

[image]

III. Under "Identity" select the account that matches your build identifier, or click "Fix Issue"

[image]

IV. If this does not fix your issue, go to "Build Settings" -> "Code Signing"

[image]

V. Finally: If this does not fix your issue, go back to the Certificate Center in the iOS Developer Center (developer.apple.com) and reprovision the certificate, then repeat these steps.